# How can I pass an array of matrices to a VertexShader?

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to learn how to use OpenGL but I'm having problems trying to pass an array of matrices to my VertexShader. I think the problem is in the VertexShader because it seems the values in modelvalue are passed correctly to the components of model, but for some reason at the end only one of the three cubes I've created is drawn.
Here's the Main code.

```
glm::mat4 model[3];
    GLint ModelLocation = glGetUniformLocation(MyShader.program, "model");
    vector<GLfloat> modelvalue;
    const int n = int(sizeof(model[0]) / sizeof(GLfloat));

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        model[i] = glm::translate(model[i], cubePositions[i]);

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            modelvalue.push_back(glm::value_ptr(model[i])[j]);
        }

    }
    glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelLocation, 3, GL_FALSE, &modelvalue[0]);
```

The VertexShader:

```
   #version 400 core
  layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position;
  layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;
  out vec2 TexCoord;
  out vec4 position0;
  out vec4 position1;
  out vec4 position2;
  uniform mat4 model[3];
  uniform mat4 view;
  uniform mat4 projection;
  void main()
 {   
position0 = projection * view * model[0] * vec4(Position,1.0f);
position1 = projection * view * model[1] * vec4(Position,1.0f);
position2 = projection * view * model[2] * vec4(Position,1.0f);
TexCoord = vec2(texCoord.x,1-texCoord.y);
 }
```

And the FragmentShader:

```
   #version 400 core

   layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position;
   layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;


  out vec2 TexCoord;
  out vec4 position0;
  out vec4 position1;
  out vec4 position2;
  uniform mat4 model[3];
  uniform mat4 view;
  uniform mat4 projection;
  void main()
  {   
position0 = projection * view * model[0] * vec4(Position,1.0f);
position1 = projection * view * model[1] * vec4(Position,1.0f);
position2 = projection * view * model[2] * vec4(Position,1.0f);
TexCoord = vec2(texCoord.x,1-texCoord.y);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Uniform Blocks](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/uniform-blocks/) might be of interest to you. They are essentially buffer objects containing an array of uniform values.

Comment: Thanks for the clue, I found the site you linked me really interesting but I still don't understand the reason why my code does not work as I hoped. I'd be really greatful if you could give a look at it.